# Copy new entry data to another list

Tags: list, workflow, sharepoint-calendar, drop-off-library

I have 20 Calendars on a site. Is there a way to copy new calendar events (meaning whenever a user add an item in the calendar) to a list. Both calendars and list are on the same site.

I can create workflow on each calendar and copy the data to TargetList but that's lots of workflow and maintenance.

How would you do it?

Comment: Why duplicate your data? A calendar is just a view on list data?

Comment: Provided that I wonder the same thing as Remko, event receivers are an alternative to workflows.

Answer (score 0):

You should create an list event receiver for the Calendar list. So that you can add the added or updated event in this list. When these event is triggered, you can create your custom code to adding/updating the item in the list you want to be the same.